# Javascript show/hide multiple divs simplified

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE**

Using both @Joe and @divakar code and combining them together, below is the updated simplified code which works! Thanks guys!

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mod1').show();

    $('.circle').click(function() {
        $('.circle').addClass('circle_active');
        $('.hide').hide();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).addClass('circle_active') // add the active class to the clicked link
        .siblings().removeClass('circle_active'); // remove the active class from the other links
        $('.' + id).show();
    });

 });
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content" id="panel2">
          <div class="row right">
            <div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns'>
                <a id="mod1" class="circle">1</a>
                <a id="mod2" class="circle">2</a>
                <a id="mod3" class="circle">3</a>
                <a id="mod4" class="circle">4</a>
                <a id="mod5" class="circle">5</a>
             </div>
          </div>

         <div class="mod1 hide">
         <p>Module 1</p>
          <table class="footable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
                  <th>Question Text</th>
                  <th>Answer Text</th>
                  <th>Tally</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Is this a training question (A)?</td>
                <td>
                    <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
                    <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
                    <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
                    <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

            <div class="mod2 hide">
            <p>Module 2</p>
            <table class="footable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
                  <th>Question Text</th>
                  <th>Answer Text</th>
                  <th>Tally</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Is this a training question (B)?</td>
                <td>
                    <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
                    <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
                    <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
                    <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>


            <div class="mod3 hide">
            <p>Module 3</p>
            <table class="footable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
                  <th>Question Text</th>
                  <th>Answer Text</th>
                  <th>Tally</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Is this a training question (C)?</td>
                <td>
                    <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
                    <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
                    <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
                    <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

            <div class="mod4 hide">
            <p>Module 4</p>
            <table class="footable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
                  <th>Question Text</th>
                  <th>Answer Text</th>
                  <th>Tally</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Is this a training question (D)?</td>
                <td>
                    <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
                    <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
                    <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
                    <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
           </div>
          </div>
```

I'm a beginner at writing javascript (as you can see with my code below!). I have written some very rough code which uses show/hide to display different div elements. It is all working correctly, but I know it's not the best way to do it. At the moment I have 4 divs which show and hide, but there's going to be 20 and that's going to be a lot of code if I do it this way.

I know that there's a better way of coding this, but my google search hasn't helped too much. I'm a beginner at this, so if someone could help explain what a better way of doing it is, it would be much appreciated. I don't know whether using arrays or loops is how to do it, but I'm not sure where to start. As you can see my code is duplicated many times and I was wondering if there was a simpler way of doing this?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mod1').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod2').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod3').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod4').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#module1').show();
    $('#module2').hide();
    $('#module3').hide();
    $('#module4').hide();


    $('#mod1').click(function(){
    $('#mod1').addClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod2').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod3').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod4').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#module1').show();
    $('#module2').hide();
    $('#module3').hide();
    $('#module4').hide();
    });

    $('#mod2').click(function(){
    $('#mod1').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod2').addClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod3').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod4').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#module1').hide();
    $('#module2').show();
    $('#module3').hide();
    $('#module4').hide();
    });

    $('#mod3').click(function(){
    $('#mod1').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod2').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod3').addClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod4').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#module1').hide();
    $('#module2').hide();
    $('#module3').show();
    $('#module4').hide();
    });

    $('#mod4').click(function(){
    $('#mod1').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod2').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod3').removeClass('circle_active');
    $('#mod4').addClass('circle_active');
    $('#module1').hide();
    $('#module2').hide();
    $('#module3').hide();
    $('#module4').show();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="content" id="panel2">
          <div class="row right">
            <div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns'>
                <a id="mod1" class="circle">1</a>
                <a id="mod2" class="circle">2</a>
                <a id="mod3" class="circle">3</a>
                <a id="mod4" class="circle">4</a>
             </div>
          </div>

         <div id="module1">
         <p>Module 1</p>
          <table class="footable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
                  <th>Question Text</th>
                  <th>Answer Text</th>
                  <th>Tally</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Is this a training question (A)?</td>
                <td>
                    <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
                    <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
                    <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
                    <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

            <div id="module2">
            <p>Module 2</p>
            <table class="footable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
                  <th>Question Text</th>
                  <th>Answer Text</th>
                  <th>Tally</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Is this a training question (B)?</td>
                <td>
                    <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
                    <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
                    <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
                    <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>


            <div id="module3">
            <p>Module 3</p>
            <table class="footable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
                  <th>Question Text</th>
                  <th>Answer Text</th>
                  <th>Tally</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Is this a training question (C)?</td>
                <td>
                    <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
                    <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
                    <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
                    <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

            <div id="module4">
            <p>Module 4</p>
            <table class="footable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
                  <th>Question Text</th>
                  <th>Answer Text</th>
                  <th>Tally</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Is this a training question (D)?</td>
                <td>
                    <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
                    <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
                    <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
                    <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="progress">
                        <span id="percent">50%</span>
                        <div id="bar"></div>
                    </div>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
           </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run this and see. i Hope this is what you expected.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.mod1').show();
   $('.circle').click(function() {
     $('.hide').hide();
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $(this).add('circle_active');
     $('.' + id).show();
   });
 });
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content" id="panel2">
  <div class="row right">
    <div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns'>
      <a id="mod1" class="circle">1</a>
      <a id="mod2" class="circle">2</a>
      <a id="mod3" class="circle">3</a>
      <a id="mod4" class="circle">4</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mod1 hide">
    <p>Module 1</p>
    <table class="footable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
          <th>Question Text</th>
          <th>Answer Text</th>
          <th>Tally</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Is this a training question (A)?</td>
          <td>
            <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
            <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
            <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
            <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="mod2 hide">
    <p>Module 2</p>
    <table class="footable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
          <th>Question Text</th>
          <th>Answer Text</th>
          <th>Tally</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Is this a training question (A)?</td>
          <td>
            <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
            <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
            <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
            <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="mod3 hide">
    <p>Module 3</p>
    <table class="footable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
          <th>Question Text</th>
          <th>Answer Text</th>
          <th>Tally</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Is this a training question (A)?</td>
          <td>
            <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
            <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
            <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
            <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="mod4 hide">
    <p>Module 4</p>
    <table class="footable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-class="expand" data-sort-initial="true">No.</th>
          <th>Question Text</th>
          <th>Answer Text</th>
          <th>Tally</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Is this a training question (A)?</td>
          <td>
            <p>A1. Incorrect</p>
            <p>A2. Incorrect</p>
            <p class="correctAnswer">A3. Correct</p>
            <p>A4. Incorrect</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent" style="left:50%;">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="progress">
              <span id="percent">50%</span>
              <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: @divakar classes are expected to be used more than once on a page, so relying on the class `mod1` etc to be unique is semantically incorrect (for what it's worth)

Comment: Yes thanks for the comment.May be he can give unique id for the first element to be showed.

Comment: Thanks again guys for all your help. I've combined the code from @Joe and divakar and with your help I've managed to make it work, although I'm not sure where I should post my updated code?

Comment: @user2706970 You could post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if you fancy, but I think there's probably enough info in the answers to be useful for people in the future. Any chance of an upvote on the answers that helped and an accept on the one that helped most? :-)

Comment: @Joe thanks for your help. I've posted the updated code in my initial post as an update. I've also given you an upvote!

Comment: @divakar thanks for your help on this! I've accepted your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the #module elements because I don't see them in your HTML, but for the #mod elements, you can do something like

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    $(this)
        .addClass("circle_active")
        .siblings()
            .removeClass("circle_active");
});
```

Comment: A side note, this will target every `<a>` on the page, even if they aren't module links. There aren't any in the posted code, but it's hard to believe there are none in the header/footer etc

Comment: Very true. You should narrow the selector scope with $("#panel2 a") or something similar, instead of just $("a").

Comment: Just as a small note, `$('#panel').on('click', 'a'...` would be more performant :-) It almost certainly won't matter on this scale, but it's still good to learn about the selector engine and its performance

Comment: Thanks guys for your help so far. I've tried using both ways you suggested, but realised it would probably be better if I showed all of the HTML code in the page so that you can see the full code. I've edited my question above. Thanks again

Comment: @Joe, where do you get that? I thought .click was a shortcut for .on("click", ...).

Comment: @Tuan : No,  `on` would get triggered for ALL the attribute in DOM for the attribute it is `bind`ed with, `click` only triggers when attached even is fired on single `bind`ed attribute only!! :)

Comment: @Tuan `on('click', 'a'...` binds the listener to one element (in this case, `#panel`) then looks at all `clicks` that bubble up to it. Just doing `$('a').on('click', func...` binds one listener to every `a` tag. The expensive part of this, processing-wise is the binding of the listener, so it's better to bind it to one common parent (but **not** the `document` element)

Comment: @Joe thanks for the explanation. So .on is the new .delegate.

Comment: Yes, and the new `.click` and the new `.mouseover` and the new ... you get the idea :P [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your HTML markup to something like this:

```
<a id="mod1" data-module="1" class="circle">1</a>
<a id="mod2" data-module="2" class="circle">2</a>

<div id="module1" class="module">
<div id="module2" class="module">
```

You can then do something like this:

```
$('#panel').on('click', '.circle', function() {
    $(this).addClass('circle_active') // add the active class to the clicked link
        .siblings().removeClass('circle_active'); // remove the active class from the other links
    $('div.module').hide(); // hide all module divs
    $('#module' + $(this).data('module')).show(); // show the one that the data-module attribute relates to
});
```

---

If you don't want to change your HTML, this should work:

```
$('#panel').on('click', '.circle', function() {
    $(this).addClass('circle_active') // add the active class to the clicked link
        .siblings().removeClass('circle_active'); // remove the active class from the other links
    $('panel').find('div[id^=module]').hide(); // hide all divs whose id starts with "module"
    $('#module' + $(this).attr('id').replace('mod', '')).show(); // show the one that the this link's id relates to
});
```

The code is slightly slower (`[^=]` is an expensive selector) and a little bit more tightly coupled to the HTML (expecting the link ID to be `#modN` as opposed to just expecting `data-module="N"`), but should work.